# Redirect homepage /page/1/ to /blog/page/1/

Tags: php, htaccess, seo, mod-rewrite

After switching from the homepage displaying latest blog posts on urls /page/1/ /page/2/ etc to a static front page with the posts displayed on /blog/page/1/ we would like to redirect the original /page/#/ to the new url /blog/page/#/

Is there a best way to do this? Perhaps a plugin, though searching has yielded little result, or htaccess redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file, add this code below-

```
Redirect 301 / http://mywebsite.com/blog/
```

Change *mywebsite.com* with your actual domain.

Comment: Thank you, Redirect 301 /page/ http://mywebsite.com/blog/ 
worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTACCESS redirects just to avoid any other users not aware of the change in the future from altering it easily through your CMS. However, if you're interested in something a bit more user friendly, there are a number of apps that build in additional slug lines for you in the page such as WP's redirection plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/